# Use taxonomy terms to set node access for a user

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have a vocabulary with two terms.

Vocab: A

Terms: b,c

I use them in two places.

> 1. First in the registration: in the `config->account->fields`.
> 2. And second one of my content type.

Now I want when a post tagged as b Just people that they are tagged with "b" in the registration can see that post.

And when a post tagged as c just the users that tagged as "c" can see the post.

Can I do this with [context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) module?
How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can set this up with Context.

There is [Access by Term](https://drupal.org/project/abt) where grants (view, update, delete) are based on the relationship between the user->term<-node.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer you should approve the answer so that the question is marked as closed/answered.

Comment: Oh,I am new in here and I forgot it.

Comment: But now there is a problem with this module.multiple access.For example the node has two tag "bread" and "milk".The user that want to access should have both of this tags.but I want he can access by just one of this tag.what should I do?